# Unable to build static library for arm6/arm7 using sourcery lite edition toolchain, C++, Eclipse on Mac OS?

Tags: c++, eclipse, macos, armv7, codesourcery

I have been trying to develop static library (.a) for arm6/arm7 using C++, Eclipse and Sourcery Lite edition ARM tool-chain on Mac OS. I have successfully setup (compile/build/configured) sourcery lite toolchain for Eclipse and able to build static library for arm9 without any error. Somehow, it does not compile/build for arm6/arm7. I don't know why ? I get following compile time error:
"selected processor does not support ARM mode `bx lr'" the same code works for arm9.

But when I check built static library using "lip -info" it says "lipo: archive with no architecture specification: libHelloCppLib.a (can't determine architecture for it)". Also I am unable to use that lib into my iPhone app.
Can somebody help ? what could be the wrong into this ? Thank You.

Comment: Google for the error text, there're plenty of topics on it.

Comment: Yes, I have googled a lot before posting this. But didn't find answer for "How to build arm6/7 static library on Mac using Sourcey, C++ & Eclipse which lipo on Mac can recognize as arm architecture." Believe me.

Comment: Are you sure you want arm6/7? Those are pretty ancient? Maybe you mean armv6 and armv7. But then you say arm9, and I'm not so sure because there isn't a v9. I believe the iPhone cores are all armv7-a but certainly not arm7.

Comment: Ah, I see the original iPhone and 3G has arm11 cores (that's armv6).

Comment: @ams Yes, I mean armv6 and armv7/s which iOS supports now-a-days. I had mentioned arm6 because in "Target Processor" (of sourcery g++ lite) list it shows arm6/7 and not armv6/v7. Anyway, I want to make it compatible for iPhone. Sorry for confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Sourcery CodeBench for Linux supports armv4, armv5, and armv7. The v5 setting should work fine on v6/v7 hardware.

If you're using the non-linux version ("EABI") then you have armv4, armv6-M, and armv7. I'm not sure the "v6-M" multilib is right for you (it's for microcontrollers); in that case you might do better with v4.

It is *possible* to specify architectures other than those officially supported (e.g. `-march=armv6`), and the compiler will do the right thing (probably), but as it doesn't come with support libraries built for those (`libgcc.a`) it'll have to use one it does have (most likely the v4 one), and you *may* get link errors. Try it and see :)

BTW, if you're using "Sourcery G++", it doesn't sound like you have the latest version. It's been called "Sourcery CodeBench" for a couple of years now.

Comment: Thank You Very Much. 
I am using "Sourcery Codebench Lite Edition For ARM EABI" (http://www.mentor.com/embedded-software/sourcery-tools/sourcery-codebench/editions/lite-edition/request?id=e023fac2-e611-476b-a702-90eabb2aeca8&downloadlite=scblite2012&fmpath=/embedded-software/sourcery-tools/sourcery-codebench/editions/lite-edition/form) on Mac Mountain Lion. I have downloaded the source code (.tar) and build it using with help of this link(http://gnuarmeclipse.livius.net/wiki/Toolchain_installation_on_OS_X). It is successfully built.

Comment: When I select "Target Processor" = arm7 then it adds compiler flag "-mcpu=arm7" but gives compilation error. As per your help, when I added flag "-march=armv7" manually then it compiles successfully now but throws "switch duplication warning".

Comment: Even with other "Target Processor" e.g. cortex A8 and cortex A9, it is successfully compiled/built with zero error/warning. But when I execute command "lipo -info" for that .a library it says "lipo: archive with no architecture specification: libHelloCppLib.a (can't determine architecture for it)".
If I ignore above error and use it into iPhone code then it says "architecture not known and reference not found" linker errors. Hope this will help more to understand the problem.

Comment: You might need to run `ranlib` on the archive to fill in the symbols tables. I don't know why it wouldn't have that in the first place though? `ar` adds the tables by default.

Comment: As for the -march problems, you should *not* have "arm7" anywhere as that's just wrong. Also, you probably want `-march=armv7-a`, because you need the `a` variant of v7 for iPhone. If you say `-mcpu=cortexa8` (or a9) then you don't need the `-march` flag. I presume the duplication warning is caused by the build system adding a flag, and then you adding another manually.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have tried to run ranlib on my archive and it gives warning: "ranlib: warning for library: *****.a the table of contents is empty (no object file members in the library define global symbols). I have searched for this but did not find workable solution.

Comment: Looks like the library has been created badly. You'll have to look into your build logs for that. I'd suggest a full clean and rebuild, just in case there's some left over junk causing it.

Comment: console log if helps: make all 
Building file: ../TestMe.cpp
Invoking: ARM Sourcery Mac OS X GCC C++ Compiler
arm-none-eabi-g++ -I/../bin -O3 -Wall -Wa,-adhlns="TestMe.o.lst" -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -c -fmessage-length=0 -march=armv7-a -MMD -MP -MF"TestMe.d" -MT"TestMe.d" -mcpu=cortex-a9 -mthumb -g3 -gdwarf-2 -o "TestMe.o" "../TestMe.cpp"
Finished building: ../TestMe.cpp

Comment: archive log: 
Building target: libHelloWorldArm.a
Invoking: ARM Sourcery Mac OS X GCC Archiver
arm-none-eabi-ar -r  "libHelloWorldArm.a"  ./TestMe.o   
arm-none-eabi-ar: creating libHelloWorldArm.a
Finished building target: libHelloWorldArm.a

Comment: 1 more thing, the same project works fine with "-arch i386" flag and also lipo goes good and able to compile for iPhone_Simulator into Xcode. I have done with creating new "build configuration" on the same project.